# Promise.all is not working/waiting JavaScript in combination with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I got a problem that the `await Promise.all` is not working in my case. I attached the code and the output I got:

```
    await Promise.all(allIndizes.map(async (index) => {
        await axios.get(uri)
            .then(async function (response) {
                let searchResult = response.data.hits.hits;
                console.log('Search Result: ' + searchResult);
                await Promise.all(searchResult.map(async (element) => {
                    await primaryKeyModel.findById(element._id).exec((err, pk) => {
                        console.log('PK, direct after search: ' + pk);
                      //DO SOME STUFF HERE BUT DELETED IT TO SHORTEN THE CODE
                        }
                    })
                    console.log('test1');
                }));
            })
        console.log('test2');
    }));
```

The output is the following:

```
test1
test2
PK, direct after search: { _id: 5bf1c0619674e2052a4f6a64 ... }
```

I actually would actually expect that the first output is the 'PK, direct after search'. I don't understand why the function is not waiting? Do someone has a hint, whats wrong here? I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) and I adopted the logic but its still not working. Thanks for the help.
I tried to shorten the code as much as possible. I only deleted statements which are not affecting the async execution.

Comment: When you pass a callback to a mongoose function, it doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Don't use `then` when you could use `await` instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose supports promises for a long time, callback-based API is obsolete, it's a mistake to use it where a promise is expected (`await`).

`then` is unwanted inside of `async` functions, this defies the purpose of using `async..await`.

It should be:

```
await Promise.all(allIndizes.map(async (index) => {
    const response = await axios.get(uri);
    let searchResult = response.data.hits.hits;

    await Promise.all(searchResult.map(async (element) => {
        const pk = await primaryKeyModel.findById(element._id);
        //DO SOME STUFF HERE BUT DELETED IT TO SHORTEN THE CODE
    }));
}));
```